# Moving servo with python arduino

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

Here I am trying to control my sg90 servo with a slider GUI made with Tkinter and sending the current value of the slider to Arduino over serial. Now the problem is whenever say, I'm moving the slider from 72 to 77 rapidly, the value it shows in the serial monitor is 7374757677.

here is the python code:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("400x400")

#some commands for arduino
import serial
uno = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

def servocontrol(var):
    uno.write(str(servo.get()).encode())

#defining the widget
servo = Scale(screen, from_=0, to=180, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=servocontrol)

#packing the widget
servo.pack()

#running the loop
screen.mainloop()
```

and here the Arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
String pypos;

int pos = 0;

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    pypos = Serial.readString();
    Serial.println("Angle: " + pypos);
    Serial.println('\n');
    int pyposint = pypos.toInt();
    myservo.write(pyposint);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(15);
  }  
}
```

now look at the output,

[image]

I've no idea what's going wrong. it would be a big help if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix if someone is also looking for an answer to this, here what I did,

Instead of sending the data as a *string* by encoding, I sent the data as an *integer in bytes* format.

```
uno.write(bytes([var]))
```

It's working fine after then.